# How we have access and invoke Visual Studio APIs / Functions such as "Find in All Files".?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

How can I programatically perform a text search against all files in a VS Solution (regardless of file type).

Visual Studio can do this via the " Find in all files ",
[image]

Is it possible to use the VS APIs to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my result after a lot of search ...

// the definition of DTE

```
namespace Utilities
{
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;

using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;

static class DteExtensions
{
    private static Dictionary<string, Project> CachedProjectsFromPath = new Dictionary<string, Project>();
    private static IEnumerable<Project> _projects;
    private static DTE2 _dte;

    static DteExtensions()
    {
        if (DTE == null) return;

        DTE.Events.SolutionEvents.ProjectRemoved += delegate { _projects = null; };
        DTE.Events.SolutionEvents.ProjectRenamed += delegate { _projects = null; };
        DTE.Events.SolutionEvents.ProjectAdded += delegate { _projects = null; };
    }

    internal static DTE2 DTE => _dte ?? (_dte = ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE2);

    internal static string SolutionName
    {
        get
        {
            return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(DTE.Solution.FullName);
        }
    }

    internal static string SolutionFullPath
    {
        get
        {
            return Path.GetFullPath(DTE.Solution.FullName);
        }
    }

    internal static string SolutionPath
    {
        get
        {
            var path = DTE?.Solution?.FullName;
            return path.IsEmpty() ? string.Empty : Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        }
    }

    internal static IEnumerable<Project> Projects => _projects ?? (_projects = DTE.Solution.Projects.OfType<Project>().SelectMany(GetProjects));

    internal static string CurrentProjectName => DTE?.ActiveDocument?.ProjectItem?.ContainingProject?.Name;

    internal static Project GetProjectFromFilePath(string filePath)
    {
        if (CachedProjectsFromPath.ContainsKey(filePath))
            return CachedProjectsFromPath[filePath];

        var project = Projects.ToDictionary(p => p, p => (filePath.IndexOf(Path.GetDirectoryName(p.FullName)) >= 0) ? Path.GetDirectoryName(p.FullName).Length : 0)
            .Aggregate((i1, i2) => i1.Value > i2.Value ? i1 : i2);

        CachedProjectsFromPath.Add(filePath, project.Key);

        return project.Key;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Project> GetProjects(Project projectItem)
    {
        var projects = new List<Project>();

        if (projectItem == null)
            return projects;

        try
        {
            // Project
            var projectFileName = projectItem.FileName;

            if (projectFileName.HasValue() && File.Exists(projectFileName))
            {
                projects.Add(projectItem);
            }
            else
            {
                // Folder
                for (int i = 1; i <= projectItem.ProjectItems.Count; i++)
                {
                    foreach (var item in GetProjects(projectItem.ProjectItems.Item(i).Object as Project))
                    {
                        projects.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //No logging is needed
        }

        return projects;
    }
}
```

}

// How to use DTE and VS Find api

```
 void VisualStudioFindAllFiles(string methodName)
    {

        // Get an instance of the currently running Visual Studio IDE.
        var objFind = DteExtensions.DTE.Find;

        //Set the find options            
        objFind.Action = EnvDTE.vsFindAction.vsFindActionFindAll;
        objFind.Backwards = false;
        //objFind.FilesOfType = $"*.{fileType}";
        objFind.FindWhat = methodName;
        //objFind.KeepModifiedDocumentsOpen = true;
        objFind.MatchCase = false;
        objFind.MatchInHiddenText = true;
        objFind.MatchWholeWord = true;
        objFind.PatternSyntax = EnvDTE.vsFindPatternSyntax.vsFindPatternSyntaxLiteral;
        objFind.ResultsLocation = EnvDTE.vsFindResultsLocation.vsFindResultsNone;
        objFind.SearchPath = DteExtensions.SolutionFullPath;
        objFind.SearchSubfolders = true;
        objFind.Target = EnvDTE.vsFindTarget.vsFindTargetSolution;

        //Perform the Find operation.
        var res = objFind.Execute();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In VS API you can use the [DTE.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.find.aspx) object to set search parameters and then call Execute(). To access VS API using C# you can use COM to call it from your own process, or write an extension for Visual Studio or a command for Visual Commander like [Prompt for a search string and list all matching lines from the current file](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/commands.html#Search) (though this is written as a VB example).